# Error with RandomGridSearchCV in Sklearn MLPRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, joblib

I found similar issues around the internet but with slight differences and none of the solutions worked for me.
I have a set of explanatory variables X (2085,12) and an explained variable y (2085,1) which I have to do some stuff on, including the use of these sklearn classes (as title). In order to get the right hyperparameters I have arranged the code as follows:

```
#solver: sgd
mlpsgd = MLPRegressor(max_iter = 1000, solver='sgd')

alpha = [float(x) for x in np.logspace(start = -6, stop = 3, num = 100)] 
hidden_layer_sizes = [(int(x),int(y),int(z)) for x in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8) for y in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8) for z in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8)]
hidden_layer_sizes.extend((int(x),int(y)) for x in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2, num = 25) for y in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2, num = 25))
hidden_layer_sizes.extend((int(x),) for x in np.logspace(start = 1, stop = 2, num = 1000))    
activation = ['logistic', 'tanh', 'relu']
learning_rate = ['constant', 'invscaling','adaptive']
learning_rate_init = [float(x) for x in np.logspace(start = -5, stop = 0, num = 20)]

random_grid3 = {'learning_rate': learning_rate,'activation': activation,'learning_rate_init': learning_rate_init,  'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layer_sizes, 'alpha': alpha}
mlp_random3 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = mlpsgd, param_distributions = random_grid3, n_iter = 350, n_jobs=-1)
mlp_random3.fit(X, y)
```

Now I know that the whole random grid is insanely huge, but I tried even with a very small one and this is not the issue (and this way it is more of a match for the type of research I am supposed to do), and I should mention that I use windows and the program starts with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

as I understood (hopefully correctly) it is needed for the multiprocessing I am asking in the second to last line of the firs part of code I attached.
Well the thing is that when I run the code some of the 350 iteration are processed correctly, but then it stops and prints this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py", line 164, in <module>
    perc = mlpottimizzata(x_train,y_train[:,i])
  File "c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py", line 72, in mlpottimizzata
    mlp_random3.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 639, in fit
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 789, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 740, in retrieve
    raise exception
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibValueError: JoblibValueError
___________________________________________________________________________
Multiprocessing exception:
...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.6.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py in <module>()
     86 del sys, os
     87
     88 # and start debugging
     89 ## Begin modification by Don Jayamanne
     90 # Pass current Process id to pass back to debugger
---> 91 vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, currentPid, run_as)
     92 ## End Modification by Don Jayamanne

...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.6.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_debugger.py in debug(file=r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py', port_num=58990, debug_id='34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14', debug_options={'RedirectOutput'}, currentPid=10548, run_as='script')
   2620         if run_as == 'module':
   2621             exec_module(file, globals_obj)
   2622         elif run_as == 'code':
   2623             exec_code(file, '<string>', globals_obj)
   2624         else:
-> 2625             exec_file(file, globals_obj)
        file = r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py'
        globals_obj = {'__name__': '__main__'}
   2626     finally:
   2627         sys.settrace(None)
   2628         THREADS_LOCK.acquire()
   2629         del THREADS[cur_thread.id]

...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.6.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_util.py in exec_file(file=r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py', global_variables={'__name__': '__main__'})
    114     f = open(file, "rb")
    115     try:
    116         code = f.read().replace(to_bytes('\r\n'), to_bytes('\n')) + to_bytes('\n')
    117     finally:
    118         f.close()
--> 119     exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
        code = b'import pandas as p\nimport numpy as np\nimport....score(x_train, y_train[:,i]))\n    print(err)\n'
        file = r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py'
        global_variables = {'__name__': '__main__'}
    120
    121 def exec_module(module, global_variables):
    122     '''Executes the provided module as if it were provided as '-m module'. The
    123     functionality is implemented using `runpy.run_module`, which was added in

...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.6.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_util.py in exec_code(code=b'import pandas as p\nimport numpy as np\nimport....score(x_train, y_train[:,i]))\n    print(err)\n', file=r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py', global_variables={'MLPRegressor': <class 'sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron.MLPRegressor'>, 'RandomForestRegressor': <class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestRegressor'>, 'RandomizedSearchCV': <class 'sklearn.model_selection._search.RandomizedSearchCV'>, '__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <class 'ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <class 'AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <class 'AttributeError'>, 'BaseException': <class 'BaseException'>, 'BlockingIOError': <class 'BlockingIOError'>, 'BrokenPipeError':
<class 'BrokenPipeError'>, 'BufferError': <class 'BufferError'>, 'BytesWarning': <class 'BytesWarning'>, 'ChildProcessError': <class 'ChildProcessError'>, 'ConnectionAbortedError': <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>, ...}, '__cached__': None, '__doc__': None, '__file__': r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py', '__loader__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, ...})
     90     if os.path.isdir(sys.path[0]):
     91         sys.path.insert(0, os.path.split(file)[0])
     92     else:
     93         sys.path[0] = os.path.split(file)[0]
     94     code_obj = compile(code, file, 'exec')
---> 95     exec(code_obj, global_variables)
        code_obj = <code object <module> at 0x02BC45F8, file "c:\Us...at\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py", line 1>
        global_variables = {'MLPRegressor': <class 'sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron.MLPRegressor'>, 'RandomForestRegressor': <class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestRegressor'>, 'RandomizedSearchCV': <class 'sklearn.model_selection._search.RandomizedSearchCV'>, '__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <class 'ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <class 'AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <class 'AttributeError'>, 'BaseException': <class 'BaseException'>, 'BlockingIOError': <class 'BlockingIOError'>, 'BrokenPipeError': <class 'BrokenPipeError'>, 'BufferError': <class 'BufferError'>, 'BytesWarning': <class 'BytesWarning'>, 'ChildProcessError': <class 'ChildProcessError'>, 'ConnectionAbortedError': <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>, ...}, '__cached__': None, '__doc__': None, '__file__': r'c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py', '__loader__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, ...}
     96
     97 def exec_file(file, global_variables):
     98     '''Executes the provided script as if it were the original script provided
     99     to python.exe. The functionality is similar to `runpy.run_path`, which was

...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py in <module>()
    159      #   print("Mean squared error: {}".format(rndf_err))
    160      #   print('Variance score: %.2f \n \n' % rndf.fit(x_train, y_train[:,i]).score(x_test, y_test[:,i]))
    161
    162         #multilayer perceptron
    163         print("Multilayer Perceptron \n")
--> 164         perc = mlpottimizzata(x_train,y_train[:,i])
    165         y_perc = perc.predict(x_test)
    166         perc_err = mean_squared_error(y_test[:,i], y_perc)
    167         err[2,i]=r2_score(y_test[:,i],y_perc)
    168         print("Mean squared error: {}".format(perc_err))

...........................................................................
c:\Users\mat\OneDrive\Desktop\TES\Analisi\Tesi.py in mlpottimizzata(x_train=array([[ 0.06      ,  2.13      ,  4.47
     , ....  0.00125208,
         0.00505016,  0.0039683 ]]), y_train=array([0.00827529, 0.00318743, 0.00103558, ..., 0.00064697, 0.        ,
       0.00333603]))
     67     activation = ['logistic', 'tanh', 'relu']
     68     learning_rate = ['constant', 'invscaling','adaptive']
     69     learning_rate_init = [float(x) for x in np.logspace(start = -5, stop = 0, num = 20)]
     70     random_grid3 = {'learning_rate': learning_rate,'activation': activation,'learning_rate_init': learning_rate_init,  'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layer_sizes, 'alpha': alpha}
     71     mlp_random3 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = mlpsgd, param_distributions = random_grid3, n_iter = 350, n_jobs=-1)
---> 72     mlp_random3.fit(x_train, y_train)
        mlp_random3.fit = <bound method BaseSearchCV.fit of RandomizedSear...urn_train_score='warn', scoring=None, verbose=0)>
        x_train = array([[ 0.06      ,  2.13      ,  4.47      , ....  0.00125208,
         0.00505016,  0.0039683 ]])
        y_train = array([0.00827529, 0.00318743, 0.00103558, ..., 0.00064697, 0.        ,
       0.00333603])
     73
     74     if mlp_random3.best_score_ is max(mlp_random1.best_score_,mlp_random2.best_score_,mlp_random3.best_score_):
     75         return mlp_random3.best_estimator_
     76     if mlp_random1.best_score_ >= mlp_random2.best_score_:

...........................................................................
C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self=RandomizedSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',...turn_train_score='warn', scoring=None, verbose=0), X=array([[ 0.06      ,  2.13      ,  4.47      , ....  0.00125208,
         0.00505016,  0.0039683 ]]), y=array([0.00827529, 0.00318743, 0.00103558, ..., 0.00064697, 0.        ,
       0.00333603]), groups=None, **fit_params={})
    634                                   return_train_score=self.return_train_score,
    635                                   return_n_test_samples=True,
    636                                   return_times=True, return_parameters=False,
    637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
        cv.split = <bound method _BaseKFold.split of KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=None, shuffle=False)>
        X = array([[ 0.06      ,  2.13      ,  4.47      , ....  0.00125208,
         0.00505016,  0.0039683 ]])
        y = array([0.00827529, 0.00318743, 0.00103558, ..., 0.00064697, 0.        ,
       0.00333603])
        groups = None
    640
    641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info
    642         if self.return_train_score:
    643             (train_score_dicts, test_score_dicts, test_sample_counts, fit_time,

...........................................................................
C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=Parallel(n_jobs=-1), iterable=<generator object BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.<genexpr>>)
    784             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:
    785                 # The iterable was consumed all at once by the above for loop.
    786                 # No need to wait for async callbacks to trigger to
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
        self.retrieve = <bound method Parallel.retrieve of Parallel(n_jobs=-1)>
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
    792             self._print('Done %3i out of %3i | elapsed: %s finished',
    793                         (len(self._output), len(self._output),

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub-process traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                         Tue Jul 17 19:33:23 2018
PID: 9280Python 3.6.5: C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
...........................................................................
C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<function _fit_and_score>, (MLPRegressor(activation='relu', alpha=811.130830...tion=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False), array([[ 6.00000000e-02,  2.13000000e+00,  4.470...25207638e-03,  5.05016074e-03,  3.96830145e-03]]), array([0.00827529, 0.00318743, 0.00103558, ..., 0.00064697, 0.        ,
       0.00333603]), {'score': <function _passthrough_scorer>}, array([ 629,  630,  631, ..., 1882, 1883, 1884]), array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,  ..., 621, 622, 623,
       624, 625, 626, 627, 628]), 0, {'activation': 'relu', 'alpha': 811.130830789689, 'hidden_layer_sizes': (24,),
'learning_rate': 'adaptive', 'learning_rate_init': 0.5455594781168515}), {'error_score': 'raise', 'fit_params': {},
'return_n_test_samples': True, 'return_parameters': False, 'return_times': True, 'return_train_score': 'warn'})]
    132
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135

...........................................................................
C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterat
```

There is nothing missing, it ends like this. Also I need to mention that mplottimizzata, which is cited in the error, is the function that contains the first block of code I attached.
I am really out of options, any help is really appreciated. Thank you all in advance :)

NB. Another part of the code does roughly  the same thing but with solver:'lbfgs' and it works smoothly, but this only confuses me even further.

Comment: In `X (12,2085)` the first dimension is the variables and the second the samples ?

Comment: Yes, 12 variables each with 2085 samples (as y)

Comment: Okay. First of all, make sure that when you call `mlp_random3.fit(X, y)` the `X` contains the samples as rows and the variables as columns. All `sklearn` algorithms need inputs as I just described.  Try to rerun the code and let me know. I think it's a problem related to visualstudio

Comment: Oh wow sorry my bad, I should've written (2085,12)... I just checked with X.shape. I'll correct the post

Comment: Perfect. Could you also add the data? If not, I will try to reproduce the problem using synthetic data.

Comment: Well I actually did't change anything, I made a mistake only writing here. So maybe I can rerun the code outside visual studio (that did't even come to my mind), if this can be the source of the error... I'll update you if anything changes.

Comment: Yes, try to run it from the terminal and let me know

Comment: Ok, even in the terminal the error pops up... As for the data, parts of the program clean and do various operations on them. Here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13d7AYUT0K50P6daTYTjJUlVL0M5Apc_V?usp=sharing I saved them as they are right before that function is called... And thank you so much for your time:)

Comment: I just noticed the counters at the edges, they are not present in the original arrays

Comment: I am going to give it a try in a bit and I will let you know

Comment: Thank you so much... I am completely stuck.

Comment: Can you run the code that i just posted and let me know if it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused when you define the grid parameters using list comprehension and the **float argument**.

This works fine for me:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X = pd.read_csv('X.csv')
Y = pd.read_csv('y.csv')

X = X.iloc[1:,1:].values
Y = Y.iloc[1:,1].values

mlpsgd = MLPRegressor(max_iter = 1000, solver='sgd')

alpha = np.arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.01)
hidden_layer_sizes = [(int(x),int(y),int(z)) for x in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8) for y in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8) for z in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2.2, num = 8)]
hidden_layer_sizes.extend((int(x),int(y)) for x in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2, num = 25) for y in np.logspace(start = 0, stop = 2, num = 25))
hidden_layer_sizes.extend((int(x),) for x in np.logspace(start = 1, stop = 2, num = 1000))    
activation = ['logistic', 'tanh', 'relu']
learning_rate = ['constant', 'invscaling','adaptive']
learning_rate_init = np.arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.01)

random_grid3 = {'learning_rate': learning_rate,'activation': activation,'learning_rate_init': learning_rate_init,  'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layer_sizes, 'alpha': alpha}
mlp_random3 = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = mlpsgd, param_distributions = random_grid3, n_iter = 350, n_jobs=-1)

mlp_random3.fit(X, Y)

print(mlp_random3.best_estimator_)
```

> MLPRegressor(activation='relu', alpha=0.03, batch_size='auto',
>   beta_1=0.9,
>          beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
>          hidden_layer_sizes=(4, 18, 1), learning_rate='adaptive',
>          learning_rate_init=0.05, max_iter=1000, momentum=0.9,
>          nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
>          shuffle=True, solver='sgd', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
>          verbose=False, warm_start=False)

Comment: Ok I'll try this out thanks... But why list comprehension works badly with a set of float like the one I implemented?

Comment: Unfortunately I just got the same error again... I adjusted the code as you said, but it stopped anyway. If this code runs for you there is clearly something I am missing in my configuration

Comment: Could it possibly be that in your 50 iterations you didn't get one of the ones that causes the code to crash? As I said (and this is still true) only after a while the error pops up. So I am guessing: is there a particular configuration of the tested parameters that simply crashes when it is called by chance? This way may be the explanation of why with iter=50 you didn't (casually) come across the error.

Comment: I am running it with `n_iter = 350` right now. It worked. I modified my code. Try something. Download the X.csv and y.csv files and copy-paste my code to see if it works. Do not change anything. !

Comment: So I created a new file with your code and it works fine, then I looked back at mine and I got why I was still getting the error: I corrected the float casting with alpha=[0.001,0.1,1,10] instead of using your np.arange(). The use of np.arange for all the float parameters definitely solves the problem. I have very little grasp on why it is so but yours is definitely the right answer, seralouk. Thank you very much for your time and skills.

Comment: I am glad that now it's working for you too. Please consider upvoting my answer. Cheers

Comment: Of course, I thought I couldn't because of low rep but I just got the minimum required. Well deserved, anyway.